# Android - getSystemService error?

Tags: android

I have followed this tutorial to get my ListView populating data -- http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296.

But it only works if I subclass my custom list adapter (MyCustomAdapter) like the tutorial does. However I would like to put this in a separate class but when I try to I end up getting an error on this line below saying that "The method getSystemService(String) is undefined for the type 
 MyCustomAdapter

```
      public MyCustomAdapter() {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
```

Any ideas how I can get this working in its own class? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getSystemService` can be called on the context. Get a handle to the context inside your adapter and you can do something like this:

```
mContext.getSystemService()
```

Comment: I tried adding a new method in my CustomHandler called setContext(Context c){this.context = c}....and then in my other class creating an instance of my Handler called adapter and saying...adapter.setContext(this). I thought that would pass in the context but it Crashes the app